# Prevent mysql process being killed by OOM killer

Tags: mysql-5.6

I need to protect mysql process so that it won't be killed when system runs out of memory, we have a bunch of adhoc job run on the server from time to time, so I would prefer the adhoc jobs being killed rather than mysql.

I know I can adjust the oom_score_adj, by setting it to -1000, I can exclude it from OOM killer's consideration. But I am not sure if I need to restart the mysql process for new oom_score_adj to take effect? Does adjust the oom_score_adj for a running process still takes effect?

I was following this post and nobody else mentioned about restarting the server for new oom_score_adj to take effect:
https://blog.rimuhosting.com/2015/12/11/dont-let-the-oom-killer-stop-mysql/

Another dumb question is that I can't seem to write to the oom_score_adj file, always getting the permission denied. The oom_score_adj is not owned by root, I have tried a couple of options but keep getting the permission issue:

```
 echo "echo '-100' > /proc/5653/oom_score_adj" | sudo -u {file_owner} sh
```

Appreciated for any help!

Comment: Restarting the server or mysqld process will loose the oom adjustment. What distro version are you running (there may be a better way than your script here)?

Comment: @danblack I am using AWS EC2 machine, the distro is `Linux version 4.9.184-0.1.ac.235.83.329.metal1.x86_64 (gcc version 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2) (GCC) )`. I have read about Ubuntu having the mechanism to specify OOM score in the init script, it does not look like REHL has the same thing?

Answer (score 9):

RHEL7 uses systemd.
[Using the OOMScoreAdjust](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#OOMScoreAdjust=) as follows:

```
sudo systemctl edit mysqld.service
```

Note: I'm not sure of the exact service name

Add the following text:

```
[Service]
OOMScoreAdjust=-1000
```

restart with:

```
systemctl restart mysqld.service
```

Check by looking at the score:

```
cat /proc/$(pidof mysqld)/oom_score_adj
```

Comment: I looked into the `/etc/init` directory on the server, it does not have any service files that remotely relate to mysql process, does this work if the way mysql setup does not rely on the service file at all for my application?

Comment: Systemd files aren't in /etc/init. Use `systemctl | grep -i mysql` to find the service name. I'm not sure how your mysql setup is, what package you've used or how it was started, your question was very short on these details. There is a check listed here.

Comment: In my case `oom_score_adj` keeps throwing 0 after the edit/restart..